# org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException how to handle this exception in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, exception

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4766773) exceeds the configured maximum (3145728) how handle this exception.... file should not exceed 3MB

if(multipartFile.getBytes().length>3145727)
return ResponseEntity.ok(AttachmentMapper.INSTANCE.mapAttachmentResponse(FILE_IS_TO_LARGE));

i tried this piece of code but still its throwing exception and in swagger its showing this..

Code    Details
Undocumented
Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Comment: You cannot simply process this error in your controller since it doesn't even get to. I guess you need to provide a handler for this exception. This could help https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring .